# Unknown Runtime Error VBScript Excel

Tags: excel, function, vbscript

I am trying to oepn an excel file, write a variable from a user input into cell D4, then read cell E4.  I keep getting ann `Unknown Runtime Error`

```
Sub ReportTP()

Dim objExcel, wb, ws

TPdate = document.getElementById("TPreportDate").value

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Application.Visible = True

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("path to file")
objExcel.ActiveSheet.Unprotect "SFGA"

Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

objExcel.Cells(D4).value = TPDate

reportVarTP = objExcel.Cells(E4).value

msgbox reportVarTP
objExcel.ActiveSheet.Protect
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save 
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close

objExcel.Application.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: What is `TPDate`? And where does `document` come from?

Comment: What is the running process that launches this and how many excel.exe's does your Task Manager's Processes tab show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set cell values from the application, not the worksheet.

```
Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
objWorksheet.Cells(D4).value = TPDate
reportVarTP = objWorksheet.Cells(E4).value
```

Use the parent [Worksheet object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224506(v=office.11).aspx) to identify the cells.

```
objExcel.ActiveSheet.Unprotect "SFGA"
```

This does not define the worksheet properly. Excel typically opens to whatever worksheet was active when the workbook was last shut down. Use `objWorksheet` or some other more definitive method of defining the worksheet to be unprotected (e.g. Worksheet [.Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196974.aspx)).